# Enlarge UICollectionViewCell when long press and dragged

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I want to scale the collectionview when longpress and dragged and when user end drag then cell should come in regular size.

I am creating demo using below steps which works fine but enlarge is not working as I expected.
[Collection View Example](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/)

Here is the gesture code I used :

```
func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    switch(gesture.state) {

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!))
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this on a collection view layout sub-class:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*) layoutAttributesForInteractivelyMovingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withTargetPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForInteractivelyMovingItemAtIndexPath:indexPath withTargetPosition:position];
    attributes.zIndex = NSIntegerMax;
    attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DScale(attributes.transform3D, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.0);
    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: I tested this for iOS 10 where it works good but without animation for scaling. On iOS 12 there is delay when these attributes are applied for moving view. I had to add animations in `handleLongGesture` which transform cell from normal state into this returned by `layoutAttributesForInteractivelyMovingItemAtIndexPath`.